# IntelliJ: Invalid .iml location and content when I choose "create new project" over "open existing project"

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, project

I have several question about how the project structure is created and stored. Here is the context: I have a git repository containing some groovy files which I use for a Jenkins library. So what is interesting us here is the "src" folder, which contains groovy classes, and the "vars" folder, which contains groovy scripts (DSL).

There's no existing IntelliJ project, no .idea folder, no .iml, no pom.xml ...

Let's say that the repository is located under:

```
C:\Toto\JenkinsLibrary
   - .git
   - src
   - vars
```

My objective is to create a Maven project from scratch.

**First Method:**

Initially, I open IntelliJ and choose "Create new project". Select "Maven", no archetype, then I enter the following information:

- Project name: I leave the project corresponding to the artifactID: JenkinsBuildLibrary
- Project location: C:\Toto\JenkinsLibrary
- More settings: Module name = JenkinsLibrary, Content root = Module file location = C:\Toto\JenkinsLibrary, Project format = .idea

Then click finish

Here, the .iml file is generated OUTSIDE the .idea folder, looking like this:

```
C:\Toto\JenkinsLibrary
   - .git
   - .idea
   - src
   - vars
   - JenkinsLibrary.iml
   - pom.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$" />
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Then soon after the content of the iml goes to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4" />
```

Also, I have been trying to reproduce this several times and it is extremely complex to get a consistent behavior, sometimes I have the iml file with no generated pom, sometimes I have the pom with no iml .... so I guess there's a huge bug here.

Finally, if I change the project structure by adding other sources folder or other modules, nothing changes in my .iml file. Then I can close IntelliJ, remove ALL .idea, .iml and pom.xml files ... to get everything back once I reopen IntelliJ, leaving me to wonder: where is that configuration actually stored ?!

**Second method:**

This time, I choose "Open existing project". I select the folder: C:\Toto\JenkinsLibrary
There's no existing project but it still works and create a new project.

The .iml file is now under the .idea project !!

```
C:\Toto\JenkinsLibrary
   - .git
   - .idea
     - JenkinsLibrary.iml
   - src
   - vars
   - pom.xml
```

Right click the module, select "Add Framework Support", Maven, and I get a pom file.

When I change the project structure, the .iml is correctly updated. Exemple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$" />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../tools/ToolJenkins/src">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../tools/ToolJenkins/src" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Now If I close IntelliJ, remove ALL .idea, .iml and pom.xml files ... I don't get anything back once I reopen the project (only the files and folder located under the module), which seems a far better behavior !

**SHORT SUMMARY:**

- When creating a new Maven project, the .iml is located at the root of the project instead of under the .idea folder and is invalid. The project structure seems to be stored elsewhere. I have no way to ship a valid project to my teammates.
- When opening a new project, the .iml is located under the .idea folder and is valid. The project structure is stored under it (with warnings that project are defined by a pom file and changes performed under the Project structure menu could be wiped). I can ship a valid project to my teammates.

I need to understand those differences and how IntelliJ works. I hope for a quick answer since this is not the first time we struggle with project structures and may well move back to another, more stable IDE is necessary.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA stores generated project files externally for Maven or Gradle based projects. You should never edit them manually or adjust any content roots and source roots via the interface as they are managed by the build system configuration (`pom.xml`) in your case.

To change or add additional source roots you need to modify `pom.xml` directly.

It looks like your directory layout [doesn't follow the standard Maven convention](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). You may need to [override it](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html) or [add additional directories](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I understand well, for a maven project, nothing should go into the .iml but rather all in the pom.xml. In this case, when I use IntelliJ project structure to add sources and modules, why is the pom.xml not updated ? The information seems stored but I failed to find where. Also, this does not explain the behavior difference I mentioned (except that in the second case, the project is not initially a maven project, could it be that ?)

Comment: Also I have a second question for you, how to I reference other projects locally on the disk ? If they are maven project I think it is easy to refer to their pom file. But if they are classical IntelliJ project with a .iml, what should I do to add their sources to my project structure ?

Comment: And finally, the standard Maven Convention does not meet the requirement for Jenkins Libraries projects, classes should go in the src folder, and DSL should go in the vars folder (a third folder exist but I do not use it), otherwise thelibrary does not work. So yeah I need to override it. Thanks a lot for the information

Comment: @Zangdar IntelliJ IDEA Maven project sync is one way, it can only import pom.xml, it will not modify pom.xml for you when you change any settings via the IDE UI. For the multiple projects use aggregate project Maven feature (parent pom file defining dependencies between the projects, then import this parent pom in IntelliJ IDEA).

Comment: Thank you I am going to have a look at the parent pom file